# Get pointer to enclosing instance from member pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, member-pointers

I have a custom class with some data members. I've got a pointer to one of the class' data member, and I would like to have a pointer to its enclosing instance. For example:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    virtual ~MyClass(){//because MyClass is not POD type
    }
};

...

int* aptr = ...; //something valid, and i know its a pointer to a MyClass::a member
MyClass* classptr = ?; //how can i get a pointer to the class instance?
```

The class is not a POD type, so the offsetof macro doesn't always work/it gives a compile warning.

Is it possible to get a pointer to the MyClass instance?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, being `MyClass` non-POD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this using well-defined C++ as casting between unrelated types is undefined behaviour.

In reality, you'll probably get away with assuming that the address of the first member of a class is the same as the address of the class offset by the size of a pointer on your system. (This pointer being the implementation of your v-table and that's reasonably consistent across C++ implementations.) Then, if you make some assumptions about the packing of the data members, then you make manual adjustments to your pointer to move from one data member to another. `offsetof` is another technique and can help you here, but it's still not well-defined in your context.

Either litter your source code with specific compiler assertions (as you are restricting portability), or adopt a different technique. I'd certainly adopt the latter.

Here's some **very** bad code which shows you how to do it. Consider

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo(){}; /*introduce a v-table*/
    int n;
};
```

And,

```
  Foo foo;
  foo.n = 0xdeadbeef; // To test
  int* p = &foo.n; // Suppose this is our pointer.
  char* pp = (char*)(void*)p; // This cast is undefined behaviour.
  pp -= 8; // Skip over 64 bit v-table. More undefined behaviour.
  Foo* ph = (Foo*)(pp); // Yet more undefined behaviour.
```

`ph` points to a `Foo` instance.

Comment: Doesn't the member pointer in the offsetof macro skips the v-table? If so, then why doesn't it work on non-POD types?

Comment: my understanding is that `offsetof` is not defined for polymorphic types

Comment: It's indeed not (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof), however by making the pointer point to the first data member, doesnt it skip the preceeding v-table? Where can the pointer manipulation go wrong?

Comment: I don't know. It will probably work once you've skipped over the v-table. But bear in mind that it will not be well-defined. I cannot recommend use of `offsetof` for a polymorphic type in *any* circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible in standard C++. `offsetof` is the only portable way to do such a thing, and it's only meant for standard-layout classes. If it doesn't work (or you can't suppress and ignore the warning), you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

`CONTAINING_RECORD` is the macro that might work for you, it's regularly used with linked lists, where the pointer to the next and previous item are embedded inside another struct.

Comment: You should probably mention that it's MSVC-specific.

Comment: I'm also trying to use this with linked lists, and this macro could be used, however I'm trying to create portable code not just Windows specific.

Comment: I would hardly call that MSVC specific. MSVC might be bundled with an sdk where it's defined, but for example [Reactos](https://git.reactos.org/?p=reactos.git;a=blob;f=reactos/include/psdk/ntdef.h;hb=c3760ed990ab91afb49a4484ab0809ad32e4e413#l212) also defines it. (And that builds fine with gcc and MSVC

Comment: In linux land this is usually called `container_of`